# Consolidate file write and read together

Tags: python-2.7, vertica

I am writing a python script to write data to the Vertica DB. I use the official library vertica_db_client. For some reason, if I use the built-in cur.executemany method for some reason it takes a long time to complete (40+ seconds per 1k entries). The recommendation I got was to first save the data to a file, then use "COPY" method. Here is the save-to-a-csv-file part:

```
with open('/data/dscp.csv', 'w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(("time_stamp", "subscriber", "ip_address", "remote_address", "signature_service_name", "dscp_out", "bytes_in", "bytes_out")) # which is for adding a title line
    for row in data:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

My data is a list of tuples. examples are like:

```
[\
('2019-02-13 10:00:00', '09d5e206-daba-11e7-b122-00c03aaf89d2', '10.128.67.132', '10.135.3.11', 'SIP', 26, 2911, 4452), \
('2019-02-13 10:00:00', '09d5e206-daba-11e7-b122-00c03aaf89d2', '10.128.67.132', '10.135.3.21', 'SIP', 26, 4270, 5212), \
('2019-02-13 10:00:00', '09d5e206-daba-11e7-b122-00c03aaf89d2', '10.128.67.129', '18.215.140.51', 'HTTP2 over TLS', 0, 14378, 5291)\
]
```

Then, in order to use the COPY method, I have to (at least based on their instruction https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/python_client/loadingdata_copystdin.html), read the file first then do "COPY from STDIN". Here is my code

```
f = open("/data/dscp.csv", "r")
cur.stdin = f
cur.execute("""COPY pason.dscp FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','""")
```

Here is the code for connecting the DB, in case it is relevent to the problem

```
import vertica_db_client
user = 'dbadmin'
pwd = 'xxx'
database = 'xxx'
host = 'xxx'
db = vertica_db_client.connect(database=database, user=user, password=pwd, host=host)
cur = db.cursor()
```

So clearly it is waste of effort to first save then read... What is the best way to consolidate the two reading part?

If anyone can tell me why my execute.many was slow it would be equally helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yes, it is both the recommended way and the most efficient way to write the data to a file first. It may seem inefficient at first, but writing the data to a file on disk will take next to no time at all, but Vertica is not optimized for many individual `INSERT` statements. Bulk loading is the fastest way to get large amounts of data into Vertica. Not only that, but when you do many individual `INSERT` statements, you could potentially run into ROS pushback issues, and even if you don't there will be extra load on the database when the ROS containers are merged after the load.

You could convert your array of tuples two a large string variable and then print the string to the console.

The string would look something like:

```
'2019-02-13 10:00:00', '09d5e206-daba-11e7-b122-00c03aaf89d2', '10.128.67.132', '10.135.3.11', 'SIP', 26, 2911, 4452
'2019-02-13 10:00:00', '09d5e206-daba-11e7-b122-00c03aaf89d2', '10.128.67.132', '10.135.3.21', 'SIP', 26, 4270, 5212
'2019-02-13 10:00:00', '09d5e206-daba-11e7-b122-00c03aaf89d2', '10.128.67.129', '18.215.140.51', 'HTTP2 over TLS', 0, 14378, 5291
```

But instead of actually printing it to the console, you could just pipe it into a VSQL command.

```sh
$ python my_script.py | vsql -U dbadmin -d xxx -h xxx -c "COPY pason.dscp FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','"
```

This may not be efficient though. I don't have much experience with exceedingly long string variables in python.

Secondly, the `vertica_db_client` is no longer being actively developed by Vertica. While it will still supported at least until the python2 end of life, you should be using `vertica_python`.

You can install `vertica_python` with pip.

```
$ pip install vertica_python
```

or

```
$ pip3 install vertica_python
```

depending on which version of Python you want to use it with.

You can also build from source code can be found on Vertica's GitHub page https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python/

As for using the `COPY` command with `vertica_python`, see the answer in this question here: [Import Data to SQL using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406744/import-data-to-sql-using-python/54409077?noredirect=1#comment95630721_54409077)

I have used several python libraries to connect to Vertica and `vertica_python` is by far my favorite, and ever since Vertica took over the development from Uber it has continued to improve on a very regular basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you clarified many of my questions. I will give vertica_python a try next week.

Comment: @DifanZhao I'm glad that this helped. For a deep dive into how Vertica writes data to disk and why bulk loading is so much more performant there is a document on Vertica's website about the hybrid storage model of ROS and WOS (https://www.vertica.com/blog/understanding-ros-and-wos-a-hybrid-data-storage-modelba-p233206/). If my response adequately answered your question, can you mark it as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: sorry for the late response... now it is marked. Always confused between upvote and the check mark :)